# How to fill in average of a column given condition in row

Tags: python, pandas

How to fill in missing data with the average of a column when row value is 0, and row value is 1 separately. 
What I have tried,

```
sample = sample.fillna(sample.loc[sample['val'] == 1].mean())
```

What I want to do is calculate the NaN When val is 1 separately and Val 2 separately. Something like this,

```
sample = Fillna(sample.mean() If row is 1) & Fillna(sample.mean() If row is 0 )
```

[Preview DataSet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jegOt.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `groupby` with `apply`, when you only have 0,1 in row .

```
sample=sample.groupby('val').apply(lambda x : x.fillna(x.mean())).reset_index(level=0,drop=True).sort_index()
```

And also better not using `lambda` here do `transform` whole df , and `fillna` with datadframe

```
sample=sample.fillna(sample.groupby('val').transform('mean'))
```

Comment: I will lose the order of my table if I do this, Is it possible to do it without?

Comment: @Will check the the update one , I only keep one here

Comment: This throws a `ValueError` for me unless I explicitly drop the index after resetting; that is, `sample.groupby('val').apply(lambda group: group.fillna(group.mean())).reset_index(0, drop=True).sort_index()` works.

Answer (score 2):

We can `groupby` the `val` column and then `fillna` missing values with `mean` values inside the group. Using `transform` here to keep the row order:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'par1': [32,43,54,23],
                   'par2': [24,43,np.nan,64],
                   'par3': [84,np.nan,73,98],
                   'val': [0,1,0,1]})

x = df.groupby('val').transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean())).join(df['val'])

print(x)
```

Output:

```
   par1  par2  par3  val
0    32  24.0  84.0    0
1    43  43.0  98.0    1
2    54  24.0  73.0    0
3    23  64.0  98.0    1
```